# Find degree of equation in a string?

Tags: java, string, equation-solving

**In JAVA:-**

Given an equation in a string: `String equation = "4*x^3-19*x^2+2*x-1=0";`, how to find its degree?

I thought of looping through the string finding positions of carets'^', get the numbers after the carets and the highest among them would be the degree of the equation. But what if the numbers are more than a single digit? Implementing this would be designing a parser of equations!

So can you tell me any other way?

Edit:

I'd like to know the way it can be done, for example using regular expressions as stated in one of the comments and not the code.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for this, match sequences of digits followed by a ^.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html, it's all documented. Once you've tried something, if you're running into a specific issue, come back here and post it.

Comment: @JasonC I didn't know I could use regular expressions. So I asked. Because I asked, I know now.

Comment: `Implementing this would be designing a parser of equations!` You are actually 100% correct. If you want this to actually work, you need to be able to evaluate the equation. It is not a trivial solution. RegEx can cover the basic cases, but there is no such regex that can find the degree in all cases.

Comment: I have a math eval library I can use by giving a value to x and evaluate the LHS of the equation. But how would I find the degree by evaluating it? Or did you mean solve the equation?

Comment: @ArjunU See some of the examples I posted under arshajii's question in a comment. I was saying you'd have to evaluate values in parenthesis of arbitrary complexity, as well as follow the rules for things like `x^2/3x^2` the degree is 0, not 2.

Comment: This is for my android app. I restrict the way user inputs the equation. It's form will be as I've stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int degree = 1;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\^)\\d+").matcher(equation);

while (m.find()) {
    int exp = Integer.parseInt(m.group());

    if (exp > degree)
        degree = exp;
}
```

We're finding all matches of `(?<=\^)\d+`. `\d+` matches a string of 1 or more digits, and `(?<=\^)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that these digits are preceded by a caret (but does not include this caret in the match).

Comment: @JasonC If he didn't want a fully functional and testable answer, then SO was not the place to ask, frankly.

Comment: That is correct, SO was not the place to ask, which is why I flagged the question.

Comment: @JasonC then why we have removed homework flag? Atleast if it homework then OP can tag it,otherwise we all presume it to be a Homework problem.

Comment: What about things like: `4*x^(3+2)` (would not evaluate 3+2), `4*x^-1` (would give 0 as the degree, since it is not `> max`), `4(x*x)` (would not evaluate as x^2), or when the equation is a fraction (would give the highest degree, instead of subtracting). I am not criticizing, just pointing out that this problem is actually a very complex one.

Comment: @Gray You'd need a full parser/grammar to resolve all of those. I assumed that the equation would always have the format of the example given in the OP's question. I agree, this problem can quickly become extremely complex.

Comment: Yes there won't be any expressions inside the exponent. No x^(3+2) or x^-1.

Comment: @ArjunU Will the expression ever have degree 0?

Comment: @ArjunU no `x^-1` but will there be fractions/parenthesis at all? ex: `1/x`?

Comment: This is for my android app. I restrict the way user inputs the equation. It's form will be as I've stated in the question.

Comment: @ArjunU Is, for example, `"0 = 0"` a valid equation?

Comment: No. If input contains no 'x' then it's not an equation. If input contains no '^' then degree is 1.

Comment: @ArjunU Then this approach should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following Regular Expression to match the values that are contained after a caret :

```
\^\d+
```

Which would explicitly match each value and then you could simply find the largest value that was matched and return it.

(*[Tutorial on Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)*)

Comment: +1 for nice link to Vogella tutorial.